# Call static function with arguments , that has no arguments successfully execute

Tags: php, function, static, static-methods

Hi I am working with `forward_static_call_array()` function , I got an example .

```
<?php

class A
{
    const NAME = 'A';
    public static function test() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        echo static::NAME, " ".join(',', $args)."<br/>";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    const NAME = 'B';

    public static function test() {
        echo self::NAME, "<br/>";
        forward_static_call_array(array('A', 'test'), array('more', 'args'));
        forward_static_call_array( 'test', array('other', 'args'));
    }
}

B::test("bar");

function test() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        echo "C ".join(',', $args)."<br/>";
    }

?>
```

Here the result is

```
B
B more,args
C other,args
```

But when I looked at the code I saw that it is calling  `B::test("bar");` other 2 `test()` functions have `func_get_args()`. But `B::test` do not have it either. So I think it should pop up an error. But it is working fine .

How is that?

- so when we are using `forward_static_call_array()` inside a function it is not necessary to have arguments in function ?

or

- PHP static functions without any argument can be called with arguments ?

Please explain it . Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `forward_static_call_array` is not special. Every function or method has this behavior.

> PHP has support for variable-length argument lists in user-defined
>   functions. This is implemented using the ... token in PHP 5.6 and
>   later, and using the func_num_args(), func_get_arg(), and
>   func_get_args() functions in PHP 5.5 and earlier.

```
function sum() {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach (func_get_args() as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.old

Comment: but this function public static function test() {
        echo self::NAME, "<br/>";
        forward_static_call_array(array('A', 'test'), array('more', 'args'));
        forward_static_call_array( 'test', array('other', 'args'));
    } , it's class B's test function , it does not have any func_get_args function ?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya , it does not matter. There is no check in language. But some functions could check it.